# Swift TableViewCell Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, tableview

My Situation: I want to save Data from an Array at Index X in an Row on Index X in Section 1.

My code is:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return setObjectToPass.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Section \(section)"
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cellEmpty = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LabelCell")
    var countCell = 0


    while countCell < setObjectToPass.count {
        let indexPaths = NSIndexPath(forRow: countCell, inSection: 0)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( "LabelCell", forIndexPath: indexPaths)

        cell.textLabel!.text = String(setObjectToPass[countCell])
        print(cell)
        countCell+=1
        return cell
    }
```

My Problem is that only the first index of the Array SetObjectToPass is passed and set into the `Cell.text`

```
 while counter < fetchResult?.count {

    let set = fetchResult![counter]
    counter+=1;
    setObject.append((set.reps?.integerValue)!)
}
```

Comment: I recommend researching the basic implementation of a `UITableViewDataSource`. What you are doing in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath(_:)` method is very odd.

Comment: Okay thank you, I'll give it a shot, still any suggestions?

Comment: what are the setObjectToPass array  values?

Comment: Those are Integer Values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the loop in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method call each row based upon `numberOfRowsInSection` count rows, simply use `indexpath.row`, Use this code,

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cellEmpty = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LabelCell")

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( "LabelCell", forIndexPath: indexPaths)

    cell.textLabel!.text = setObjectToPass[indexPath.row] as? String

    return cell
}
```

hope its helpful

Comment: I used `String(setObjectToPass[indexPath.row])` to save the label Text
Since it can't cast Int to String

**WORKING NOW!**

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing the `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath:)` method wrongly.

Remember, every delegate method in `UITableViewDelegate` is like asking you a question. For example, `numberOfSectionsInTableView(_:)` is like asking you "How many sections do you want in your table view?". You answer the question by returning a value.

`tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath:)` is similar. It asks a question as well. It asks "What should I display in the table row at this index path?"

In your code, it seems like you want to give multiple answers - looping through the array and attempting to return multiple times. But it doesn't work that way, you can only give one answer.

In the first iteration of the `while` loop, the execution hits `return` and stopped. That's why you only see the first table cell.

Thus, you should change your code so that it only gives *one* answer to the question:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LabalCell")
cell.textLabel?.text = String(setObjectsToPass[indexPath.row])
return cell
```

Comment: I am getting an "Use of unresolved identifiers" for setObjectToPass.

Declaration is here:

`class TableViewControllerResult: UITableViewController {
    
    //Fetch variable from other ViewController
    var counterToPass: Int!
    var counterSetToPass: Int!
    var setObjectToPass: [Int]!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print(counterToPass)

        
    }`

Comment: Oops! I actually meant `setObjectToPass` @HendrikBreezy

Comment: In combination with the other Comment its working, tyvm!